# Correct directory structure for Spring 3 / JSF 2 application?

Tags: spring, jsf, directory, war

At work, I have seen several ways of setting up a directory structure for this type of app. Maybe there is more than one correct answer. Here is how I am setting up my directory structure - is it correct? Or is there a better way of configuring it? (I am packaging this in a WAR file)

- /webappTopDir

  - /src

    - /main

      - /java (controllers and other classes)
      - /webapp

        - /subfolder1 (Spring secured subfolder)
        - /subfolder2 (Spring secured subfolder)
        - /resources

          - /js
          - /images
          - /css
        - /WEB-INF (contains application-context.xml, security.xml, faces-config, web.xml, and spring taglibs)

          - /classes (contains custom JSF messages and logging properties)

            - META-INF (contains persistence.xml)
          - /lib
          - /templates
        - /META-INF (contains context.xml)

This structure works, but I still want to make sure it is best practice. What I find really odd is the META-INF under WEB-INF/classes, but from what I see in the Oracle docs, that is what you need if packaging your app into a WAR [Oracle Managing Entites](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, META-INF directory is under WebContent directory. I think what you've thought odd was right. But definitely there's no right or wrong way. There is just a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The term "correct" implies that there is an objective standard for folder layouts. Here are the objective standards that I know about:

1. Project specific layout. Whatever history the project is embodied in the layout and you should continue to maintain that layout until your are forced out of it.
2. Developer community layout. Your shop determines how the layout is implemented. This layout was built up through a number of generations of programmers and the developmental forces that are being addressed. Changing a developer community mind set is not an easy job, even if it is just yourself.
3. Build tool layout. Many build tools have specific layouts because of the conventions used by the toolset. Make, Ant, Seam 2, Spring, Maven 1, Maven 3, JBoss Forge all seem to have their own conventions arising out of the developer communities that created the toolset. Each toolset has ways of customizing the layout.
4. Library/framework layout. Spring has a (set of) specific layout(s) that work well with its build set ups.

To answer your specific question though, I suggest that you use a Spring template to build out your directory layout. You might try the following tutorial:

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

As you follow the tutorial, learn the reason why the Spring build chain needs things to be in specific locations. This allows you to justify the tutorial layout, and apply similar reasoning to your own application layout.

Comment: Helpful answer, but my app is not Spring MVC, but rather JSF with Spring providing security. If there is no 'better way', but instead many equally good ways to combine the different directory layouts, then this answer is sufficient.